# PHP - Post select option value to index.php adding user

Tags: php, html, mysql

I got a `nuevo.php` that means 'new client' to insert in a mysql database.

I have a lot of input text to register data into mysql, like this :

```
<label for="Nombre">Nombre : </label><br/>
<input width="50" type="text" class="form-control" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" placeholder="Introduce nombre">
```

---

... all inside this ...

`<form action="" method="POST" role="form">`

---

And a button like this :

```
<button type='submit' value='Modificar' class='btn btn-primary'>Registrar</button>
```

---

And in `index.php`, I got this code to register data into mysql finally ...

```
$app->post('/nuevo', function() use($app, $db){
    $request = $app->request;
    $nombre = $request->post('Nombre');
    $apellidos = $request->post('Apellidos');
    $nifcode = $request->post('NIF');
    $direccion = $request->post('Direccion');
    $email = $request->post('Email');
    $telefono = $request->post('Telefono');
    $estado = $request->post('Estado');
    $provincia = $request->post('Provincia');
    $numProvincia = $request->post('numProvincia');

$dbquery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Clientes(Nombre, Apellidos, NIF, Direccion, Email, Telefono, Estado, Provincia, numProvincia) 
        VALUES (:nombre, :apellidos, :NIF, :direccion, :email, :telefono, :estado, :Provincia, :numProvincia)");

        $res = $dbquery -> execute(array(
        ':nombre' => $nombre, 
        ':apellidos' => $apellidos,
        ':NIF' => $nifcode, 
        ':direccion' => $direccion, 
        ':email' => $email,
        ':telefono' => $telefono, 
        ':estado' => $estado,
        ':Provincia' => $provincia,
        ':numProvincia' => $numProv));
```

---

**It register all well, all EXCEPT Provincia**.

For this, in `nuevo.php` I'm using another thing that isn't an input text : **`SELECT OPTION`**

```
<form method="get">

                <?php
                $host="localhost";
                $link=mysql_connect($host, "USER", "PASS");
                $db=mysql_select_db("pvenecia", $link);
                $cdquery="SELECT DISTINCT Provincia, numProvincia FROM Clientes ORDER BY Provincia";
                $cdresult=mysql_query($cdquery);
                ?>

                <select id="Provincia" name="Provincia" style="width: 300px" onchange="javascript:cambiarProvinciaSeleccionada();">
                    <?php
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($cdresult)) { 
                        $defect = "";
                        if ($row['Provincia'] == 'SIN INFO. PROVINCIA') {
                            $defect = " SELECTED ";
                        }
                        echo "<option value='".$row['numProvincia']."' ".$defect.">".htmlentities($row['Provincia'])."</option>";
                        echo "<br/>";

                    }; 

                    mysql_close($link); 
                    ?>
                </select>
            </form>
```

---

**I NEED TO KNOW HOW TO GET THE VALUE FROM SELECT OPTION SELECTED, FOR WHEN I SUBMIT, POST INTO INDEX.PHO AND REGISTER THIS VALUE CORRECTLY**. Thanks.

Comment: The Provincia select box should be in same form with other inputs.

Comment: what does the onchange js do? if it makes the val empty then u wont get data. also try to use my_sqli.

Answer (score 1):

For retrieving the value it does not make any difference between text message or select / drop-down.
value can be retrieved using GET/POST method by name. Ex:

```
$provincia = $request->post('Provincia');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think because your form in `nuevo.php` is in method="GET" try to change it in method="POST" and use

```
$request->post('Provincia')
```